# Tektro rear brake does not stay closed

Tags: brakes

Two weeks ago I had an issue about my brakes QR not working and asked about on this site [Road rim bike brakes don't open when using the release](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77754/road-rim-bike-brakes-dont-open-when-using-the-release)

I got some help - and I am very thankful for that - pointing at replacing my cables. I did so and cleaned the brakes in the process. I followed the Park Tools book for that. During the first ride the rear brake opened, and since then I have not been able to close it. See this video https://i.imgur.com/RouHYPP.mp4

It looks like the mechanism which is supposed to maintain the brake closed has gone too soft.

Comment: There is something wrong with the "lock device".  It should be grabbing onto the mating surface to hold things closed.

Comment: @daniel is it something that can be inspected or fixed?

Comment: It requires inspection by a perceptive mechanic.